# Is it possible to create pdb in dev cpp?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

How can one create  pdb file in dev cpp project ?

I did following changes but none is creating the file . What can I do to make it for me . I want to create it because in windbg I need to provide it the path of pdb so that it helps me debug[image] .

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't use dev-c but you will also have to tell the compiler to generate debugging info and also, probably, turn off optimization.

Comment: yes thats off too .. updated question too :)

Comment: ditch dev-c++ which is horrible IDE and move to visual studio

Comment: According to https://sourceforge.net/p/dev-cpp/discussion/48211/thread/affae65a/, there is a bug where you have to set the debugging options in the project options because the compiler/link options don't work. Worth a try.